# Got string "AA, BB, CC" would like "'AA', 'BB', 'CC''" - could I do it smarter?

Tags: c#, string

I know I could to this with:

```
        string input = "AA,BB,CC";
        string output = "";
        foreach (var item in input.Split(','))
        {
            output += string.Format("'{0}',", item);
        };
        output =output.TrimEnd(',');

        Assert.AreEqual("'AA','BB','CC'", output);
```

But there might be smarter and faster ways of doing this.

Thanks for any ideas.

Larsi

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. Accepted answer was more than 3 times faster. The other attempt was about 2 times faster than my attempt. But main reason for asking was that I was hoping for some more elegant syntax, and that I got. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't know if this would be slower but it's shorter:

```
string output = "'" + input.Replace(",", "','") + "'";
```

Comment: +1 I just did a quick profiling, and this one-liner is faster than one call to Split alone.

Comment: I don't know the internals of string.Replace, but i _guess_ it shouldn't allocate memory for each `,` encountered. Maybe the "'" at start and end would, but not sure. But they are all guesses. Can anybody confirm?

Comment: Although functionally, if the input string has spaces with commas, e.g. `"AA, BB, CC"`, the output `"'AA',' BB',' CC'"` _may_ not be as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Lumen I can confirm that it's more than 3 times faster than my attempt.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it will be faster than the code you have, but you can use LINQ and write something like:

```
string output = String.Join(",",
    input.Split(',').Select(token => "'" + token + "'"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
output = String.Join(",", input.Split(',').Select(s => "'" + s + "'"));
```

Comment: I think you need `Split(',')` *not* `Split(",")`

Comment: Ah that's my bad - the project I dropped that into when I wrote it has a `string.Split(string)` extension method in it. You think too harshly of people.

Comment: @PhonicUK ok, removed downvote. But actually you haven't checked your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
output = String.Join(",", input.Split(',').Select(s => "'" + s + "'"));
```